# Converting to flash video

Tags: video, conversion, flash, encoding

I'm trying to convert a .dv video from a camcorder to flash video to show on my organization's website. I'm having issues using VLC (the file ends up empty or not compressed, depending on different options), so I either need help with VLC or other recommendations. If you're recommending software, it absolutely must be free. (My organization is non-profit)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Download this free video converter](http://www.erightsoft.org/GetFile.php?SUPERsetup.exe)

Here is a GIF on how to convert the file. Note: Save the image to see it over again or open the image in a new tab to see it over again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using an Eee PC and it claims (and I've verified) that the bottom buttons do not show when the screen res < 1024x768

Comment: Sorry dude didnt know.

Comment: Shadow - you're going to have problems crunching video files on an Eee PC aren't you?? Irrespective of whether you can see the buttons...

Comment: I used to rely on SUPER for video conversions before I found FFcoder. The UI of SUPER is ridiculously cluttered and the options can be confusing for non-advanced users. Also, the site to download it from is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

FFcoder is a wonderful piece of freeware capable of converting videos to nearly every conceivable format in existence. I use it frequently. The drag-and-drop interface is very useful. It's very easy to use for both regular users and advanced users. There's an plethora of extra features that come with it as well. The only caveat is the .NET Framework requirement. But it doesn't hurt to get it if you don't have it already.

[image: FFCoder Main Window]

You can download it here: [FFCoder Website](https://teejee2008.wordpress.com/ffcoder/)

Make sure to download and install the software listed under "*Requirements*" if you don't have them already. There's also a portable version available as well. It's also being actively developed and the developer responds to bug reports quickly.

I would just change the "*File Format*" drop-down selection to "Flash Video" and just drag-and-drop the videos into the window. Click the "*Output*" button to change the location of the converted files. Then, just hit start and wait for it to convert.